How does Inscryption auto-build a deck for you?
Once you’ve started a new game in Inscryption after defeating Leshy, the game switches to a ”game-inside-a-game” version with older and more pixelated graphics. The deck building system changes with this, such as being able to edit your deck at any point with whatever cards you’ve ever picked up.
One of the new features is an auto-build button. The game will build a deck for you based on what cards you have.
How does the algorithm it uses to do this work? And are the decks it builds viable for play? I defeated the graveyard Scrybe with autobuilt decks only, so they can’t be too bad…?
